# Create input with button and add to array Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

I want to click a button to create new input fields with every click.
And after I write something in the input fields I want to click a submit button.
By that everything should be added to an array, so each input is one element in this array.
I can create input fields with a function and its working.
But I´m stuck trying to add these to an array.

Can anyone help me out?
Would be much appreacheated.

Kind Regards

This is my code

```
<body>
<header>
    <form name="input" method="get">
    </form>
    <a onclick="add_field()" class="addButton"><button>Add</button></a>
</header>
<main>
     <div id="input-container"></div>
</main>

<!--Javascript to add input-->
 <script>    
    

        let array = [];
        const BtnAdd = document.querySelector(".btn-add");
        const InputContainer = document.getElementById("input-container");
        
        BtnAdd.addEventListener("click", AddNew);

    function add_field () { 
            var myParent = InputContainer;
            var inputList = document.createElement("input");
            inputList.setAttribute('class','InputField');
            inputList.setAttribute('id','InputField');
            myParent.appendChild(inputList);
    };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a submit function, which is called when the submit button is clicked. Then you need to get the newly created input elements whenever the submit function is called, and extract the values. See below a working example. (especially check the `submit` function).

Here is also a [codepen](https://codepen.io/dcts/pen/bGWPgeW)

```html
<body>
<header>
    <form name="input" method="get">
    </form>
    <a onclick="add_field()" class="addButton"><button>Add</button></a>
</header>
<main>
     <div id="input-container"></div>
</main>
<a onclick="submit()"><button>Submit</button></a>


<script>
let array = [];
const BtnAdd = document.querySelector(".btn-add");
const InputContainer = document.getElementById("input-container");
        
BtnAdd.addEventListener("click", AddNew);

function add_field () { 
  var myParent = InputContainer;
  var inputList = document.createElement("input");
  inputList.setAttribute('class','InputField');
  inputList.setAttribute('id','InputField');
  myParent.appendChild(inputList);
};

function submit() {
  console.log("submitted");
  // get all input elements
  const inputElements = document.querySelectorAll("#input-container > input");
  // make array of input elements (to be able to iterate)
  const inputElementsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(inputElements);
  // save contents of input to array
  array = inputElementsArray.map(d => d.value);
  alert(`array content is: ${array}`)
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do is use `querySelector` on your container element to find all the newly added input elements and read their value

```
const inputs = InputContainer.querySelectorAll(".InputField");
const array = [...inputs].map(i => i.value);
```

Note that id's should be unique so you shouldnt add the same `id` to every newly created element. Below is a working example

```js
const BtnAdd = document.querySelector(".btn-add");
const BtnCreateArray = document.querySelector(".btn-create-array");
const InputContainer = document.getElementById("input-container");

BtnAdd.addEventListener("click", () => {
  var inputList = document.createElement("input");
  inputList.setAttribute('class', 'InputField');
  InputContainer.appendChild(inputList);
});
BtnCreateArray.addEventListener("click",() => {
  const inputs = InputContainer.querySelectorAll(".InputField");
  const array = [...inputs].map(i => i.value);
  console.log(array);
});
```

```html
<header>
  <form name="input" method="get">
  </form>
  <button class="btn-add">Add</button>
</header>
<main>
  <div id="input-container"></div>
  <button class="btn-create-array">Create array</button>
</main>
```